# Delphi variants and TValues

Tags: delphi

I know that `Variants` are slow when I convert data types, even when I simply add two variant values holding integers. I have discovered also another similar thing that looks variant-like called `TValue`.

What's the difference between them?

I was considering to make a classic speed test using the `TStopWatch`, but I don't think that it is enough to understand the differences

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`TValue` is not Variant-like.  It will not perform data conversions like `Variant` does.  If you ask `TValue` to return a different type than it is currently holding, and the held type is not assignment-compatible with the requested type, (ie it would not normally *implicitly* convert in normal language syntax), then `TValue` will raise an `EInvalidCast` exception.

Answer (score 19):

`TValue` is not meant for converting data types but for transportation of values when using RTTI.

It only allows for data types to be converted that are directly assignment compatible (like for example `Integer` to `Int64` or `Byte` to `Integer`). But unlike `Variant` it does not allow for example converting a `string` containing a number to be cast to `Integer` but raises an `EInvalidCast` exception.